# Total charge in electron cloud in a hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

Essentially, the problem I'm trying to solve is

> The
>   potential at a distance $r$ from the nucleus that is generated by an electron in a
>   hydrogen atom is given by:
>     $$V(r) = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_o}\left(\frac{e^{-2r/a}-1}{r}+\frac{e^{-2r/a}}{a}\right) $$
>   where $a$ is a constant (which I think is the radius of the atom). Use Gauss' law to calculate the total charge in the electron cloud.

To use Gauss law for a spherical surface (in the form $E\cdot 4\pi r^2 = Q/\varepsilon_o$), we need field $E = -\frac{dV}{dr}$. If we evaluate the field $E$ at $r=a$, so that we contain the entire cloud, we get that 
$$E(r) = \frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_oa^2e^2}(e^2-5).$$

And I think that something is incorrect - the electron cloud should have charge $-q$, but there's no way to get that from the above. What am I missing?

(all similar questions on this site are with charge density $\rho$ instead of the potential, so *they are not useful*).

Comment: Why do you evaluate E at r=a?

Comment: @my2cts I though that the electron cloud ends at $r=a$ (it can't span beyond the atom, yeah?), so that's the radius I've choosen for the gaussian surface.

Comment: The electron cloud extends to infinity.

Comment: This seems like a very odd place to apply Gauss' Law. You would need an infinitely large Gaussian surface to be able to encapsulate the entire charge density... (You get the right answer in the $r \rightarrow \infty$ limit)

Comment: It sounds like the point is to show that the charge is $q$ by taking the limit $r\rightarrow\infty$.   Note that this can be done before or after the integration.

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the electric field for a very large $r$, you get $$E = -\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}$$

Notice the negative, I think your electric field at a has the wrong sign.

Using Gauss’ law, $E A = Q / \epsilon_0$, noticing that $A = 4 \pi r^2$, you get simply get $-q = Q$.

I’m guessing that this equation then doesn’t take into account the nucleus, so that the charge enclosed by the Gaussian surface is just the charge of the electron cloud.